# Trouble with setting conditionals to parse through data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

## seems like we have some extra artifacts that appear as the dataset changes firms. write a piece of code that checks to see where the tickers change, and delete all artifacts from those points

```
for (y in 1:nrow(longitudinal)){
 if (longitudinal[y,2] != longitudinal[y-1,2])
 {longitudinal[y,] = NA }}
```

hey guys, I am trying to remove values from a column in a dataset according to a change in column 2, the name value. Unfortunately I am getting the error

> Error in Ops.data.frame(longitudinal[y, 2], longitudinal[y - 1, 2]) :
> ‘!=’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

I cannot think of a different way to compare the elements in the name column in order to set the condition for the NA's to correspond to the change in the name. Would appreciate any help thinking through this.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop had to start from 1 row down ie

```
y in 2:nrow(longitudinal)
```

because the conditional would've had the second element starting at row 0.